# How to configure EntityManagerFactoryBuilder bean when testing Spring Boot Batch application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot Batch application that I'm writing integration tests against. However, I'm getting the following error about the EntityManagerFactoryBuilder bean missing when running a test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.example.DatabaseConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder]: : 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

My understanding is that Spring Boot provides the EntityManagerFactoryBuilder bean on application startup. How can I have the EntityManagerFactoryBuilder provided when running tests?

Here's my test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseConfig.class, BatchConfiguration.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })

public class StepScopeTestExecutionListenerIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<Foo> reader;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    public StepExecution getStepExection() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoodData() throws Exception {
       //some test code
    }
```

Here's the DatabaseConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.example.repository"}, 
entityManagerFactoryRef="testEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "testTransactionManager")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.example.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("testLoad")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager testTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory testEntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(testEntityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you configuring it yourself in the first place? Remove that class and instead in your `@SpringApplicationConfiguration ` use the application class and not individual configuration classes.

Comment: Because when I replace @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseConfig.class, BatchConfiguration.class}) with my application class i.e. @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BatchApplication.class), it runs the batch application.

Comment: The whole point of the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` that it knows what to do with a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation (or the 3 indiviual annotations), however you are only loading 2 configuration files and thus there is going to be no auto configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Then, perhaps I need to modify my post. I need to prevent the full batch application from running when performing test.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I created another post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910981/how-can-i-prevent-my-spring-boot-batch-application-from-running-when-executing-t. I'm leaving this post as-is in case others have the same question. If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it since you answered my question in regards to this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When (integration) testing a Spring Boot application that is what you should do. The `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is intended to take your application class (the one with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) as it will then be triggered to do much of the same auto configuration as a regular Spring Boot application.

You are only including 2 configuration classes and as such no auto configuration will be done.