# How can I prevent my Spring Boot Batch application from running when executing test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot Batch application that I'm writing integration tests against. When I execute a test, the entire batch application runs. How can I execute just the application code under test?

Here's my test code. When it executes, the entire batch job step runs (reader, processor, and writer). Then, the test runs.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BatchApplication.class))
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
public class StepScopeTestExecutionListenerIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<String> reader;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    public StepExecution getStepExection() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoodData() throws Exception {
       //some test code on one met
       File testFile = testFolder.newFile();

       PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(testFile, "UTF-8");
       writer.println("test");
       writer.close();
       reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(testFile));
       reader.open(getStepExection().getExecutionContext());
       String test = reader.read();
       reader.close();
       assertThat("test", equalTo(test));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to create `application.properties` file in test resources (e.g. src/main/resources) with this content:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

You need to make sure that integration test reads. For that you may need to use `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` this way:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class, 
         initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Comment: The application is already using /src/main/resources/application.yml. Is there a way to point to a different configuration file for testing?

Comment: besides putting one in `src/test/resources`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried putting it in src/test/resources. Now, the job is disabled during testing and regular application run.

Comment: I added another profile to /src/main/resources/application.yml. In that profile, I set spring.batch.job.enabled=false. Then, set it as the active profile on the integration test class via @ActiveProfiles. So, that along with what you noted in your answer seems to do what I need (i.e. do not run the batch job during integration test. run the batch job during application run).

Comment: This is strange. Test resource shouldn't  be included into production artifact. Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: I'm using gradle. I'm running my test from within Eclipse via Run As-> JUnit Test. When I create src/test/resources/application.yml, Eclipse generates a marker noting that "The resource is a duplicate of src/main/resources/application.yml and was not copied to the output folder".